# How to do a bit mask operation Pharo?

Tags: bitwise-operators, pharo

In Pharo, I want to do bit masking on integers, which looks like this in Python:

```py
((b1 & 0x3F) << 4) | (b2 >> 4)
```

I know that `&` and `|` work in Pharo, but I'm pretty sure they're not bit-wise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

but you are wrong :)

look at the implementation of `&`, `|`, `<<`, `>>` in Pharo:

```
& aNumber
    ^ self bitAnd: aNumber

| anInteger
    ^self bitOr: anInteger

<< shiftAmount
    "left shift"

    shiftAmount < 0 ifTrue: [self error: 'negative arg'].
    ^ self bitShift: shiftAmount

>> shiftAmount
    "right shift"

    shiftAmount < 0 ifTrue: [self error: 'negative arg'].
    ^ self bitShift: 0 - shiftAmount
```

That basically means that your code will work out of the box except for the translation of hex C style to hex Pharo style:

```
((b1 & 16r3F) << 4) | (b2 >> 4)
```

Comment: So, are those implementations of `bitAnd:` etc superfluous? Ahah, I see `&` and `|` are a kind of syntactic sugar.

Comment: yup. For those like me who work a lot on bit masking ;)

Answer (score 2):

From this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jdevoo/8e8866cd6087e05790841d0f20b2e377):

````
"************************************************************************
 * Bitwise Manipulation:                                                *
 ************************************************************************"
| b x |
x := 2r1111 bitAnd: 2r0100.                                 "and bits"
x := 4r3333 bitAnd: 2r011011011.                            "and with different bases"
x := 2r1111 bitOr: 2r0100.                                  "or bits"
x := 16rFF bitXor: 8r5252.                                  "xor bits mixing bases"
x := 16rFF bitInvert.                                       "invert bits"
x := 2r0100 bitShift: 2.                                    "left shift"
x := 2r0100 bitShift: -2.                                   "right shift"
x := 2r0100 >> 2.                                           "divide by four"
x := 2r0100 << 2.                                           "multiply by four"
x := 2r0100 bitAt: 3.                                       "bit at position (0|1)"
x := 2r0100 highBit.                                        "position of highest bit set"
b := 16rFF allMask: 16r0F.                                  "test if all bits set in mask set in receiver"
b := 16rFF anyMask: 16r0F.                                  "test if any bits set in mask set in receiver"
b := 16rFF noMask: 16r0F.                                   "test if all bits set in mask clear in receiver"```
````

So, you could write `((b1 & 0x3F) << 4) | (b2 >> 4)` as

```
((b1 bitAnd: 16r3F) << 4) bitOr: (b2 >> 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this a lot, you'll probably don't want to apply this to Integers. They have a special encoding that doesn't allow you to use all 64 bits. Take a look at Collections-Native